# Date conversion in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdate

I have to compare date (coming from server) with today's date. The date from server is in different format (that is, date format may be 2015-09-08 or 2015-09-08T11:30:00+0530)

How can we compare these different date format with today's date in iOS (Objective-C).

Comment: Update your question with what you have tried so far. Explain what issues you are having.

Comment: Why did you tag your question with the swift tag if you wanted an answer in Objective C?

Answer (score 2):

Actually, there is no matter if you want to compare 2 dates in different formats, the problem is to compare date values you have to ensure 
1. They are converted to the same timezone. 
2. Use - (NSComparisonResult)compare:(NSDate *)anotherDate method

In addition, if you want to convert your date string response from HE to NSDate, you can do as below

```
+ (NSDate *)dateFromDateString:(NSString *)dateString withFormat:(NSString *)format {
    NSDateFormatter *formatter = [NSDateFormatter new];
    formatter.dateFormat = format;
    return [formatter dateFromString:dateString];
}
```

Moreover, in term of comparing 2 dates in specific components (such as year, month, day and without hour, min or second) you have to use `NSDateComponents`

```
- (BOOL)date:(NSDate *)aDate isEqualToDateIgnoringTime:(NSDate *) anotherDate
    {
        NSCalendarUnit unitFlags = (NSCalendarUnitYear|NSCalendarUnitMonth|NSCalendarUnitDay|NSCalendarUnitHour|NSCalendarUnitMinute|NSCalendarUnitSecond);
        NSDateComponents *components1 = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] components:unitFlags fromDate:aDate];
        NSDateComponents *components2 = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] components:unitFlags fromDate:anotherDate];
        return ((components1.year == components2.year) && (components1.month == components2.month) && (components1.day == components2.day));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try with this

```
  -(void)dateFormateTest{
 NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
formatter.dateFormat = @"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss Z";
[formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];
[formatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone]];
[NSTimeZone resetSystemTimeZone];
NSDate *date = [formatter dateFromString:@"2015-10-06 12:39:12"];
NSLog(@"date: %@",date);

NSComparisonResult result = [date compare:[NSDate date]];
if (result == NSOrderedDescending) {
    NSLog(@"Past");
}else if (result == NSOrderedDescending) {
    NSLog(@"future");
}


}
```

Comment: Why do you set two different date formats on the date formatter?